# How to get full Path from t:inputFileUpload?

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I have one browse button in jsf.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <t:inputFileUpload value="#{skuController.name}"  storage="file"/>
            <t:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{skuController.splitNuggets}" />
</h:form>
```

I just want to fetch full path in controller.
like D:\Mapping\APPS\chaptersheet\Book.xls
But I got only Book.xls

In my controller I have written like that.

```
    private UploadedFile name;
    (getter/setter)
    public void splitNuggets() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>---"+ name.getName());
}
```

I CANT GET IT WHAT IS MY MISTAKE .

Answer (score 0):

Actually you cant get the full path because of security reason in latest browser. and name is enough.